# How to correctly annotate object variable?

Tags: python, annotations

how can I correctly annotate object as variable in the function? Here is the example:

```
class A():

    def funct_one(self, name: str, rec: B) -> None:
        ...

class B():
    ...
```

As you can see I tried to do <rec: B>, but it pops up error.

Comment: You have to define `B` before `A` in order to use it as a type hint in `A`.

Comment: If you need a forward reference, write it as a string: `rec: "B"`

Comment: @Barmar or do `from __future__ import annotations`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in the current version of Python, annotations are resolved when the signature is first evaluated by the interpreter. This means that the values need to be resolvable at this time.

What you want to do is called a *"forward reference"*. In order to make forward references possible, Python is actively changing the way that annotations are resolved and offload this work to later when all references would be resolvable.

During the time before resolving the annotations, the values are stored as simple strings. Certain libraries like mypy or tools like pycharm are already able to handle this today.

So you have three options:

1. Refactor to avoid the forward reference
2. Use strings explicitly when defining the annotation
3. Enable the future behavior using the `__future__` module.

---

**Option 1:** Reorder the class to have `B` defined before it is referenced. This is not always possible depending on the layout.

```
class B:
    pass

class A:
    def funct_one(self, name: str, rec: B) -> None:
        pass
```

---

**Option 2:** Use the string version of the annotation. Tools like mypy or pycharm will resolve the reference to the real class for you.

```
class A:
    def funct_one(self, name: str, rec: "B") -> None:
        pass

class B:
    pass
```

---

**Option 3:** (This is my preferred option) Use delayed annotations processing by importing future annotations features. In this mode we are able to easily do forward references in type-hints for things that haven't been defined yet

```
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
    def funct_one(self, name: str, rec: B) -> None:
        pass

class B:
    pass
```

*Warning: Some libraries that do annotations processing rely on the old implementation, but for simple code this will work fine. This will eventually be how python operates by default and the `__future__` import will not be necessary.*